# Angular ng-view/Router not working

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular and was using Angular 1, However I always get 404 Resource not available error.
Here is the Code that I am doing.I am using ng-view and I am stuck in the part as to why my application does not route to the login or the dashboard page

```
index.html :

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="sampleApp" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="webapp/js/vendor/angular.js"></script>
<script src="webapp/js/vendor/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="webapp/js/app/app.js"></script>
<script src="webapp/js/app/loginController.js"></script>
<script src="webapp/js/app/dashboardController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('head')).append(angular.element('<base href="' + window.location.pathname + '" />'));
  </script>
</head>
<body >
<ng-view></ng-view>

<a href="/login">Login</a>
<a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
</body>
</html>

var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp',       ['ngRoute','loginModule','dashboardModule']);    sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){

    $routeProvider
    .when('/login',{
        templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
        controller: loginController
    })
    .when('/dashboard',{
        templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html',
        controller: dashboardController
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);

This is my loginController.js

angular.module('sampleApp',[])
.controller('loginController',function($scope,$location){
    $scope.login = "In Login Controller";
});

dashboardController.js

angular.module('sampleApp',[])
.controller('dashboardController',function($scope,$location){
    $scope.dashboard = "In Dashboard Controller";
});

Please let me know what wrong am I doing.
Sorry for my English.
```

Comment: what is LoginModule and dashboardModule?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Following Modification I have done to your code.
create login.html inside partials folder aside of index.html file

```
{{login}}
```

create dashboard.html inside partials folder aside of index.html file

```
{{dashboard}}
```

create index.html with following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="sampleApp" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript">
        angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('head')).append(angular.element('<base href="' + window.location.pathname + '" />'));
    </script>-->
</head>

<body>
    <ng-view></ng-view>

    <a href="/login">Login</a>
    <a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
</body>

</html>
<script>
    var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute']);
    sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });
        $routeProvider.when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
            controller: 'loginController'
        }).when('/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'dashboardController'
        });
    }]);
    sampleApp.controller('loginController', function($scope, $location) {
        $scope.login = "In Login Controller";
    });
    sampleApp.controller('dashboardController', function($scope, $location) {
        $scope.dashboard = "In Dashboard Controller";
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I followed the above , although i Changed the href to                                     <a href="/Sample_Angular/login">Login</a>
<a href="/Sample_Angular/dashboard">Dashboard</a>,                                the same changes done accordingly in app.js file, but I Still get that error.

Comment: Use some grunt serve or gulp serve to serve your app to specific host. or just use serve plugin from npm.